# XAMPP: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, xampp

I am trying to create a connection to an API in a local environment using Xampp, and I am getting this error:

`cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Now I have already googled around, and tried a solution using these steps, but I am still recieving the same error:

```
1) I have downloaded cacert.pem from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
2) I have put the cacert.pem file in folder: C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl
3) I have changed the path of [curl] in php.ini to curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
4) I have changed the path of [openssl] to openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
5) I have restarted Xampp
```

Any advice/ideas would be appreciated on how to solve this error!

Comment: Add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); and/or curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); in the curl option reuqest